# SQL Server 2000 sp? odbc vs OleDb

Tags: sql-server-2000, odbc, oledb

Our clients wnat us to retreive data from SQL Server 2000. It is unknown whether they have any service packs installed for that SQL Server. Assuming the worst (no sp), will there be a problem using OleDb driver to work with SQL Server 2000?

Comment: No, the OleDB driver works just fine with SQL Server 2000 - actually, the native .NET SqlClient would work even bette.r...

Comment: I have problem using native sqlclient, it refuses to connect.

Answer (score 1):

OleDb is working fine without any sp.